# Understanding Catalog URL Rewrite Indexer

Tags: url-rewrite, reindex

I've truncated the `core_url_rewrite` table with about 5000000 records. After that I run the Catalog URL Rewrite Indexer which created 1782612 records. Then I run it again and the table had 2251930 records. So, every time I run the indexer, I get more records in the table. Does anyone know why?
Thanks

Comment: See comments: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5655/optimize-catalog-prouct-url-rewrite

Comment: Closing as duplicate; please update your question if that seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 4):

I also asked a similar question a while back:

[Magento core_url_rewrite table excessively large](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17553/magento-core-url-rewrite-table-excessively-large)

I've managed to stabalize the issue as follows:

**Step 1:** Rewrite the Catalog URL model (Using your own module: [How To](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/))

> Note: If you overwrite the core file without using a rewrite this will
>   render your instance of Magento incapable of future upgrades.

As per Jahnni's solution on [the MagentoCommerce boards](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/416476/P0/), `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php` around line 807

**From:**

```
if ($product->getUrlKey() == '' && !empty($requestPath)
   && strpos($existingRequestPath, $requestPath) === 0
)
```

**To:**

```
if (!empty($requestPath)
           && strpos($existingRequestPath, $requestPath) === 0
)
```

**Step 2:** Truncate

Truncate the `core_url_rewrite` table

**Step 3:** Reindex & Flush Caches

Initiate the re-indexing process on Core URL Rewrites.
Thereafter, you'll want to flush the Magento cache & storage cache.

`System` → `Cache Management` → `Flush Magento Cache`

`System` → `Cache Management` → `Flush Cache Storage`

Voila, you're all set. You'll notice if you re-run the indexer, the table should stay constant in size (unless you've added more products inbetween or if you have duplicate category names).

Comment: A word of warning: if you `truncate core_url_rewrite` you are deleting all of your custom rewrites as well as the system ones - these won't be regenerated by the subsequent reindex and will be lost permanently!

Comment: True. instead delete the entitytype="product" (for products alone)

Answer (score 3):

I guess there are several reasons why this may happen. One of the more obvious is when you have several products with the same URL key.

Given you have two products both named "Test" with both products having the same URL key "test". Magento will create two URL rewrites: one for test.html and one for test-2.html. If you re-run the Rewrite Indexing process, Magento will start creating a further redirect for the test-2.html URL and so on. As you can guess that's not a wanted behaviour but it happens pretty often, especially with stores having configurable products with many simple products sharing the same name (e.g. clothes with different sizes and colors).

To dive deeper into this problem and find the cause for your growing URL rewrite table we would need more detail, I'm afraid.